# Nginx redirect after slash in location

Tags: regex, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have domine name https://example.com/API/, I wanted to redirect anything given after /API/ for example :

```
https://example.com/API/test to https://example.com/API/
```

Below is my Nginx conf

```
 location @error {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        root  /var/www/html/test/;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        internal; 
  }

  location ~*/api {
    rewrite ^/api(.*) $1 break;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3100;
    client_max_body_size 60M;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    error_page 502  @error;
  }
```

That from the above example if /API/ gets 502 I am redirecting it to. PHP file is working fine, But if there is anything given after /API/test it is showing 404 not found.

Answer (score 0):

You can have something of this sort:

```
server {
  root /var/www/html;  #your own values
  
  server_name _;       #website name

  location @error {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        root  /var/www/html/test/;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        internal; 
    }


  location /api {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3100;
        client_max_body_size 60M;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        error_page 502  @error;
  }
}
```

So basically you would have to use `location /api {}` directive and that would work.